# Is anyone creating tickets or printing bar codes from CiviCRM?

Tags: printing

We would like to be able to store and print machine-readable codes (bar codes or QR codes).  We might print these on receipts for event registrations, to act as tickets, or on signin sheets or ID cards to track attendance at meetings, etc.

I saw a reference in an old question about this here on Stack Exchange, but nothing about it in the CiviCRM documentation.  Is someone offering an extension perhaps that does this?  Has anyone integrated CiviCRM with a code-generating Word-Press plugin?  Do you think it's possible?

Answer (score 2):

Years ago we used '[QR Code Checkin](https://civicrm.org/extensions/qr-code-checkin)' extension for one of our clients. Using the extension you can email the QR code to participant and same extension can also be used to confirm the registration.